# Set max date dynamically in ngx-bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a bs Date Range picker in angular. On component load I am setting the mindate to current date. But how can I set the max date after selecting min Date.

Because I want to restrict the user that he/she can not select max date not more than 3 days after selecting the min date. For an example if user select 5th Apr 2020 as start date then user's max date will be restricted to 7th Apr 2020. Days will be disabled after 7th Apr 2020.

**Component HTMl -**

```
<input type="text" 
#dp="bsDaterangepicker"
formControlName="bookingPeriod"
[minDate]="bookingStart"
[maxDate]="bookingEnd"
bsDaterangepicker
[bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true, rangeInputFormat: 'DD MMMM, YYYY', displayOneMonthRange: true }" />
```

**Component Ts -**

```
public bookingStart: any = Date;
public bookingEnd: any = ""; 

constructor() {
  this.bookingStart = new Date();
  this.bookingStart.setDate(this.bookingStart.getDate());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you modify the example on the [ngx-bootstrap page](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/3.3.0/#/datepicker#min-max) a little bit with the help of this: [Javascript: Adding days to any date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10018287/9544229), you could write something like this:

**datepicker.ts**

```
  bsValue = new Date();
  bsRangeValue: Date[];
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;

  constructor() {
    this.bsRangeValue = [this.bsValue, this.maxDate];
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() + 10);
    this.maxDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() + 3);
  }
```

**datepicker.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Max Date</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input class="form-control"
             placeholder="Datepicker"
             ngModel
             bsDatepicker
             [minDate]="minDate"
             [maxDate]="maxDate">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input class="form-control"
             placeholder="Daterangepicker"
             ngModel
             bsDaterangepicker
             [minDate]="minDate"
             [maxDate]="maxDate">
    </div>
  </div>
```

This should help you.

Comment: Working... Thank you